# How to add space around a titled border?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, border

I created a titled border like

```
TitledBorder title = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("title");
panel.setBorder(title);
```

and want to have space around it. I only know that this is possible with an empty border like

```
panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
```

But in this case I've got already my titled border and therefore can't add an empty one. So how do I solve that problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `CompoundBorder`

For example...

```
setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10), BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("title"));
```

Will add a 10 pixels to the outside of the border and then the title border inside.  If you prefer, you can switch it so that well be 10 pixels between the title and the internal contents

Take a look at [How to use borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more details

Comment: thanks... i just realized about compoundborder :D

Comment: I had to switch the order of the border arguments for this to work.

Comment: @Jasper It will depend on you needs, the constructor is `outside`, `inside` ordered, so may example, as stated, will add a 10px empty space around the outside of the title